# Overlapping of labels in the markers of a chart line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I have created a chart line with two plot and enable the mark label using `nodes near coords`, but I get the overlapping labels as shown in the following figure:

[image]

How can I fix this? is there a way that labels do not overlap?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
        \begin{axis}[legend pos=south east, scale = 1, xlabel=\textbf{data},ylabel=\textbf{values}, xticklabels={
        n10-1,
        n10-2,
        n30-1,
        n30-2,
        n50-1,
        n50-2,
        n70-1,
        n70-2,
        n100-1,
        n100-2,
        n150-1,
        n150-2,
        n200-1,
        n200-2}, xtick={1,...,14}, x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},legend style={ at={($(0.5, 1.1)$)},anchor=center, legend columns=2},
        height=7cm,   
        width=\textwidth, 
        enlarge x limits=0.08,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        grid style=dashed,
        nodes near coords
        ], 
                
                
                \addplot [blue, mark size= 2pt, mark = square*, mark options=solid]  coordinates {
                (1,6.44)
                (2,4.89)
                (3,42.12)   
                (4,41.66)   
                (5,151.19)      
                (6,114.45)  
                (7,99.11)
                (8,137.8)
                (9,103.42)
                (10,112.87)
                (11,214.07)
                (12,288.96)
                (13,271.66)
                (14,418.66)
                };
                \addlegendentry{A};

                
                \addplot  [black, mark size= 2pt, mark = square*, mark options=solid] coordinates {
                (1,20.73) 
                (2,19.31)
                (3,91.22)   
                (4,77.76)   
                (5,170.58)      
                (6,136.79)  
                (7,143.81)
                (8,213.29)
                (9,122.17)
                (10,145.95)
                (11,225.66)
                (12,293.39)
                (13,319.23)
                (14,439.86)
            };
            \addlegendentry{B};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the nodes smaller and/or move them above/below like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
        \begin{axis}[legend pos=south east, scale = 1, xlabel=\textbf{data},ylabel=\textbf{values}, xticklabels={
        n10-1,
        n10-2,
        n30-1,
        n30-2,
        n50-1,
        n50-2,
        n70-1,
        n70-2,
        n100-1,
        n100-2,
        n150-1,
        n150-2,
        n200-1,
        n200-2}, xtick={1,...,14}, x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},legend style={ at={($(0.5, 1.1)$)},anchor=center, legend columns=2},
        height=7cm,   
        width=\textwidth, 
        enlarge x limits=0.08,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        grid style=dashed,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}
        ], 
                
                
                \addplot [blue, mark size= 2pt, mark = square*, mark options=solid, nodes near coords align={below}]  coordinates {
                (1,6.44)
                (2,4.89)
                (3,42.12)   
                (4,41.66)   
                (5,151.19)      
                (6,114.45)  
                (7,99.11)
                (8,137.8)
                (9,103.42)
                (10,112.87)
                (11,214.07)
                (12,288.96)
                (13,271.66)
                (14,418.66)
                };
                \addlegendentry{A};

                
                \addplot  [black, mark size= 2pt, mark = square*, mark options=solid,nodes near coords align={above}] coordinates {
                (1,20.73) 
                (2,19.31)
                (3,91.22)   
                (4,77.76)   
                (5,170.58)      
                (6,136.79)  
                (7,143.81)
                (8,213.29)
                (9,122.17)
                (10,145.95)
                (11,225.66)
                (12,293.39)
                (13,319.23)
                (14,439.86)
            };
            \addlegendentry{B};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with non overlapping nodes]

Comment: That is 'nodes near coords align={below or above}'! thanks